# How can I get the matrix model in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I'm doing some programming with OpenGL and I need to get the model matrix to fulfill my own calculation purpose. As everybody know, the OpenGL library function can only get the modelview matrix by using

```
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
```

Could you please tell me how to get the matrix and implement this function by using C?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` is part of the immediate mode which is deprecated since `3.x`. If you learn OpenGL you should take the time to learn how to use glsl and vbo.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL matrix stack (granted that it's available - this thing is disabled in GL core profile since, if i remember correctly, version 3.2, or OpenGL ES 2.0) contains two matrix types - projection and modelview. Separate modeling and view matrices have no practical use for 3D drawing purposes, so GL doesn't distinguish them (on a contrary, D3D had separate projection, world (same name for modeling) and view matrices).

Modelview is just `modeling * view`, there is no magic here. However, extracting modeling (if you know view) is quite math-heavy. So, if you have, by GL calls, created modeling matrix, why do you want to extract it back? Don't you still have initial data to recreate matrix? (which is recommended since newer GL have no matrix functions, so at some point you'll have to calculate matrices yourself and give GL only final ones). Even for lower GL profiles, it's often better to perform matrix calculations yourself and only then load result with glLoadMatrix() calls.

Comment: Oh, so now I understand what he actually wants to achieve.